# Django project 'site cant be reached'

Tags: django, ubuntu

I've created a Django project and a virtual environment where I installed python on my Ubuntu server. When I try to run the development server by typing

```
$ ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I get the usual

> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>   April 01, 2017 - 11:36:55
>
> Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'myproject.settings'
>
> Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
>
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

However, when I go to the site [my ip address]:8000 I get a 'This site can’t be reached' message, anyone know any causes for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was a security group problem in the server, I didn't have custom TCP rule 8000 enabled